# sharing data between controllers of different html pages using rootscope

Tags: angularjs, rootscope

```
<td colspan="1">{{case.Name}}</td>
<td colspan="1">{{case.total}}</td>
<td colspan="1">{{case.passed}}</td>
<td colspan="1">{{case.failed}}</td>
<td colspan="1" ng-click="showAll(case.Name)">{{case.totalCheck}}</td>
```

When the user clicks this column (`totalCheck`), the name is stored in a variable `$rootscope.name` and another html page is opened where i require this variable.
This controller is named angular1.

```
analyzer.run(function($rootScope) {
    $rootScope.name= '';
}); 

$scope.showAll=function(item){
    $rootScope.name= item;  
    $window.open('/scripts.html');
}
```

For the other page, i have another controller

```
var analyzer = angular.module('analyzer', []);

analyzer.controller('angular2', function($scope, $rootScope) {
    alert($rootScope.name);
});
```

Here it says the value of name is undefined. how do you share the variable between 2 pages ? .

Comment: are both your controllers belongs to the same module??

Comment: yes. But when the other html opens it reloads the angular file again and creates new scopes. So maybe the value is reset then

Comment: if you can use a service or factory  instead of $rootScope

Comment: won't the same thing happen ?  In the new page, it'll load the angular file and create new scopes . so the initial value in the service will be set for the variable ?

Comment: Where you want to show that html page?

Comment: just next to the previous one in a new tab !

Comment: Why dont you use ngRoute?  See documentation @ https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use ngRoute here.

Follow below steps (you can even use `hrf="#/scripts.html/{{case.Name}}"` and can pass `case.name` as `routeParams` and no need to use `$rootScope`):

1) Include //ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular-route.js
2) Change your function as per below.

```
analyzer.run(function($rootScope,$location) {
        $rootScope.name= '';
    }); 

  $scope.showAll=function(item){
        $rootScope.name= item;

      $location.path('/scripts.html');
  }
```

3) Add config for your routing.

```
var analyzer = angular.module('analyzer', ['ngRoute']);
analyzer.config(function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
    .when("/scripts.html", {
        templateUrl : "scripts.html"
    });
});
```

Comment: I'll try this but $location.path will open it in the same tab. Routing might work if i use this same location but not in a new tab